# Magento 2.2.0 - Block not called in Custom Module

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, controllers, magento2.2

I am working on a simple module and trying to display a block. All that is showing up is a blank page. If I put an echo "blah"; exit() in my controller, it shows the output. No errors in my log files. Below is the code

**registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Magento2_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Magento2/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
        <router id="standard">
                <route id="magento2" frontName="helloworld">
                        <module name="Magento2_HelloWorld" />
                </route>
        </router>
</config>
```

**Magento2/HelloWorld/Block/Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Magento2\HelloWorld\Block;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, array $data = []) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }


    public function sayHello()
    {
    return __('Hello World');
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```

**Magento2/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Magento2\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;


class Index extends Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**Magento2/HelloWorld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento2\HelloWorld\Block\Index" name="HelloWorld_index" template="Magento2_HelloWorld::helloworld.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>

</page>
```

**Magento2/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/helloworld.phtml**

```
<?php echo $block->sayHello(); ?>
```

After running **http://localhost/mage2/helloworld/index/index** URL, I can see controller being executed but the block is not being called.

[image: Module Output]

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is ok in your code. You just need to change this file

> Magento2/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml

**`router id` and `frontName` must be same**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
                <module name="Magento2_HelloWorld" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Now remove var/generation folder and flush cache

Comment: I have answered this question before your answer...You have copied my answer i think

Comment: @Ranganathan.S. I think you are new in StackExchange. I have copied the code from the question same as you did. This does not mean that I copied your answer :)

Comment: I have posted exact answer  already...why you post same answer again...

Comment: @Ranganathan.S StackExchange is not only for one user. Everyone can post an answer here. If you think that my answer is a copy of your answer then you can flag it without more explanation and unwanted commenting here. Comment is used for only solve questions issue, not for this type of unwanted comment.

Comment: Good Smalification Bro

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your routes.xml
change your id to `helloworld`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
        <router id="standard">
                <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
                        <module name="Magento2_HelloWorld" />
                </route>
        </router>
</config>
```